# Extracting the Last Substring in a String

Tags: teradata

The string pattern is:

'\string_1\string_2...string_n-1\string_n'

Delimiter is: "\"

I have to:

- extract 'string_n'
- on the right side I have to eliminate blanks

How can I do it with Teradata?

Answer (score 1):

What's your Teradata release? If you're on TD14 you can use a simple regular expression:

```
REGEXP_SUBSTR(s, '[^\\]+$')
```

Find all characters not equal to a backslash at the end of the line.

Previously you might have the INSTR UDF:

```
SUBSTRING(s FROM INSTR(s, '\', -1, 1) + 1)
```

And eliminating blanks is a basic

```
TRIM(TRAILING FROM  SUBSTRING(s FROM INSTR(s, '\', -1, 1) + 1))
```